mangaing multiple multilingual website with same domain
I have multiple multilingual website that I need to configure with same domain.
Example : www.abc.com as main domain
And for subsites Australia www.abc.com/en-au
France  www.abc.com/fr-fr and www.abc.com/en-fr
How to manage multiple multilingual website with same domain.
What will be best site definition to handle this.
